# How to convert c++ code to cobol correctly

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I have written code to get the number that appears the most in an array. The main function will make a call to readData which will read data into the array that I passed to the readData subroutine. After the readData subroutine has executed, i use the mode function to find the number that appears most in an array.

Example array: |1|2|2|1|1|

Output generated: 1

My c++ code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mode(int array[]){
    int max = 0, num;
     int count;
    
    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i){
        count = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<5; ++j){
            if(array[i] == array[j]){
                ++count;
            }
             if(max < count){
                max = count;
                num = array[i];
            }
        }
    }
    
    cout << num << endl;
}

void arrayData(int array[]){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    
    mode(array);
}

int main()
{
    int array[5];
    arrayData(array);

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to convert the above c++ code to cobol, I am using gnuCobol. The code i have generated so far is bellow.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. Main.

DATA DIVISION.
    
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 array.
        05 val PIC X(1) OCCURS 5 TIMES.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    CALL 'READDATA' USING array.
STOP RUN.

*> readData: fills the array with user diffined digits
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. READDATA.

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. ***> error appears here**
    01 array.
        05 val PIC X(1) OCCURS 5 TIMES.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
        UNTIL I > 5
        SET I TO 1
        ACCEPT array(I) FROM SYSIN.
        SET I UP BY 1
    END-PERFORM.
    
    CALL 'MODE' USING array.
    
EXIT PROGRAM.

*> mode: gets the number that appears most in the array
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. MODE.

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 array.
        05 val PIC X(1) OCCURS 5 TIMES.
    01 maxv PIC(1) VALUE 0.
    01 counter PIC(1).
    01 num PIC(1).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
        UNTIL I > 5
            MOVE 0 TO counter
        
            PERFORM VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1
            UNTIL J > 5
            
            IF array(I) = array(I) THEN
                SET counter UP BY 1
            END-IF
            
            IF maxv < counter THEN
                MOVE counter TO maxv
                MOVE array(I) TO num
            END-IF
            
            SET J UP BY 1
            END-PERFORM.
            
        SET I UP BY 1
    END-PERFORM.
    
    DISPLAY "Mode: "num.
EXIT PROGRAM.
```

I am getting the following error:

Error: syntax error, unexpected "WORKING-STORAGE", expecting "END PROGRAM" or "PROGRAM-ID"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several issues with the code. The reported error appears to have been the absence of an `END PROGRAM` statement to separate the first program from the second.

Other errors include:

- Using `SET` statements unnecessarily
- Passing the `array` without a `LINKAGE SECTION` or `USING` phrase
- Missing `DATA DIVISION` statements
- Missing data items
- Improper subscripting
- Including a "separator period" before a scope terminator
- Invalid `PICTURE` clauses

These issues are shown in comments in the following code. Compare the original code with the modified code.

---

Modified code:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. Main.

   DATA DIVISION.
        
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 array.
       05 val PIC X(1) OCCURS 5 TIMES.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       CALL 'READDATA' USING array.
   STOP RUN.
   END PROGRAM MAIN. *> ADDED

   *> readData: fills the array with user diffined digits
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. READDATA.
   DATA DIVISION. *> ADDED
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. *> error appears here**
   01 I PIC 9.
   LINKAGE SECTION. *> ADDED
       01 array.
           05 val PIC X(1) OCCURS 5 TIMES.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING ARRAY. *> MODIFIED
       PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
           UNTIL I > 5
   *>      SET I TO 1 *> REMOVED
           ACCEPT VAL   (I) FROM SYSIN  *> MODIFIED
   *>      SET I UP BY 1 *> REMOVED
       END-PERFORM.
        
       CALL 'MO-DE' USING array.
        
       EXIT PROGRAM.
   END PROGRAM READDATA. *> ADDED

   *> mode: gets the number that appears most in the array
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. MO-DE. *> 'MODE' IS A RESERVED WORD
   DATA DIVISION. *> ADDED
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 maxv PIC 9 VALUE 0. *> MODIFIED
   01 counter PIC 9. *> MODIFIED
   01 num PIC 9. *> MODIFIED
   01 I PIC 9. *> ADDED
   01 J PIC 9. *> ADDED
   LINKAGE SECTION. *> ADDED
   01 array.
       05 val PIC X(1) OCCURS 5 TIMES.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING ARRAY. *> MODIFIED
       PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
           UNTIL I > 5
               MOVE 0 TO counter
            
               PERFORM VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1
               UNTIL J > 5
                
               IF VAL  (I) = VAL  (J) THEN *> MODIFIED
                   ADD 1 TO COUNTER *> MODIFIED
               END-IF
                
               IF maxv < counter THEN
                   MOVE counter TO maxv
                   MOVE VAL  (I) TO num
               END-IF
                
   *>          SET J UP BY 1 *> REMOVED
               END-PERFORM *> MODIFIED
                
   *>      SET I UP BY 1 *> REMOVED
       END-PERFORM.
        
       DISPLAY "Mode: "num.
       EXIT PROGRAM.
   END PROGRAM MO-DE. *> ADDED
```

Input:

```
1
5
5
2
3
```

Output:

```
Mode: 5
```